# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with iOS8 ABMembersViewController

Tags: ios, ios8

Since iOS8 went live the other day, I've started to get lots of crash reports to do with address book / contact functionality. It's one of those annoying ones where the stack trace gives no clues about where in my code the problem originates. I've tried reproducing this in the iOS8 simulator by using the most obviously related functionality, but so far without joy (I don't own any devices running iOS8 yet).

The actual error is: **Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010**

Here's the stack trace:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib  objc_msgSend + 16 respondsToSelector:
1   AddressBookUI    -[ABMembersViewController membersController:shouldAllowSelectingPersonWithRecordID:] + 100
2   AddressBookUI    -[ABMembersFilteredDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 488
3   UIKit            -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 544
4   UIKit            -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2360
5   UIKit            -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 172
6   UIKit            -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 572
7   QuartzCore       -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 168
8   QuartzCore       CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 320
9   QuartzCore       CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
10  QuartzCore       CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 276
11  QuartzCore       CA::Transaction::commit() + 436
12  QuartzCore       CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
13  CoreFoundation   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
18  UIKit            UIApplicationMain + 1488
19  Prayer Partner   main.m line 14 main
20  libdyld.dylib     start + 4
```

I thought I'd post it here in case anybody has had any similar errors.

Comment: When you say "no clues", do you mean that `membersController:shouldAllowSelectingPersonWithRecordID:` never calls `respondsToSelector:`?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would know - as far as I'm aware ABMembersViewController is an iOS private API

Comment: In case anybody else gets this same issue, I don't know for sure that this is the fix, but be aware that in iOS8 they totally changed the behaviour of the delegates etc for the contact selectors, as well as how they interact with permissions and so on. Make sure you get permissions *before* showing the contact selector, and make sure that you implement the new delegate methods

Comment: It's been over a month and I've not seen this crash again since making those changes to the delegates etc